# Questions list pager link has overescaped ampersand

Tags: bug, status-completed, pagination, questions-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links in the old review panel contain HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144724/links-in-the-old-review-panel-contain-html-entities)
>   [“Get 30 more” while reviewing first questions resets filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146092/get-30-more-while-reviewing-first-questions-resets-filters)

The pager links are coming out as:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes&amp;pagesize=30
```

instead of:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes&pagesize=30
```

The links still work, but don't change the page size.

This happens both when logged in, and anonymously. I tested on a `/questions/tagged` page and on a normal questions page and they both have the erroneous behaviour.

I originally found this on DBA.SE, and reproduced here on Meta.

Comment: For linking purposes: [Mobile user profile activity paging over-escapes page querystring parameter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146077)

Comment: All three seem to be related; however, it's unclear if it's the same issue. Edit: also, IMO, fixing the Questions page is more important than the other two.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it *wasn't* the same issue.

Comment: Ah, looking again I did [already report something similar for search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145948/mobile-search-page-controls-fail-due-to-double-encoding), but only the first of the three issues I mentioned (this one was the second) was fixed, so meh. Hopefully fixing this will fix the search pager as well. If not, this is a note to whoever's taking care of it.

Comment: This seems to be the explanation the source of these bugs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145656/186964

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out as I type.

Comment: @Kevin: This only partially fixed [this other issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144724/links-in-the-old-review-panel-contain-html-entities) where the links at the bottom for disabling random ordering, etc are still escaped.